# Looking Up the Next Value after I locate the correct row of the value i need

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup, offset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWhyK.png)If i have the unique number, how can i get the next value from column M? Say, my unique number is 10, then the value that i need is the value from 13. I attached the picture to illustrate.

[image]

I tried doing Offset function but doesn't work. Please help.

In the second screenshot, I used this:

=let(Σ,xmatch(K2,K:K)+1,+tocol(indirect("M"&Σ&":M"),1))

By the way, I am using Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX-XMATCH with dynamic offset:

```cpp
=LET(n,10,k,K2:K,m,M2:M,
     INDEX(m,XMATCH(n,k)+
       MMULT(
         TOROW(QUERY(FILTER(ROW(m),n<=k,""<>m),"limit 2")),
         {-1;1})))
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,xmatch(10,K:K)+1,
     +tocol(indirect("M"&Σ&":M"),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! and if I make the "10" dynamic, can i just use the cell number?

Comment: Hi again, it doesnt seem to work if I make the "10" as dynamic. Can you check?

I have attached another screenshot

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: you can use this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ScpzWpaYRRvpXeGPmXkn3gwzlmrC3_AxpRpcV4IJre4/edit#gid=1920303083

i need to get the values on the expected output if I am given the Unique number. Thank you for all the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MULblmG.png tested the formula with your test data & it is giving the expected output

Comment: You are right. It did pulled up the next point. Thank you so much! What a legend!